# Can a genvar variable be used as a constant input to a module instance in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I want to use a generation block in verilog to implement multiplexers that each of them gets the genvar variable as a constant input. The simulation shows no error. However, I want to make sure that "i" is considered a 9bit constant.

```
genvar i;
generate
for (i=254; i>-1; i=i-1) begin  : ripple

    mux mux_0(.sel(in[i]), .input1(i), .input0(input_num[i+1]), .out(input_num[i]));
end    

module mux(
input sel,
input [8:0] input0, input1,
output reg [8:0] out
);

always@(*) begin    
out = 0;
    if(sel)
        out = input1;
    else 
        out = input0;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Run it thru Vivado synthesis then take a look at how the tool interpreted the code.  Use the 'view schematic' ability and explore the structure that was implemented.

Comment: Yes, a genvar is a constant, no, genvar is 32-bit wide. You have no constant  inputs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned, a `genvar` is treated as a constant 32-bits signed value. You can select a bit range of a `genvar`, like you can do for an `integer`.

In Verilog it would be: (note: `i[8:0]+1'b1` would evaluate to a 10-bit value)

```
for (i=254; i>-1; i=i-1) begin : ripple
    mux mux_0(.sel(in[i[8:0]]), .input1(i[8:0]), .input0(input_num[i[8:0]+1'b1]), .out(input_num[i[8:0]]));
end
```

If you have SystemVerilog you can use:

```
for (i=254; i>-1; i=i-1) begin : ripple
    mux mux_0(.sel(in[9'(i)]), .input1(9'(i)), .input0(input_num[9'(i+1)]), .out(input_num[9'(i)]));
end
```

Answer (score -1):

A `genvar` gets expanded in a constant `integer` type, which is a 32-bit signed value. It's the same as if you could write the following manually.

```
mux ripple[254].mux_0(.sel(in[254]), .input1(254), .input0(input_num[255]), .out(input_num[254]));
mux ripple[253].mux_0(.sel(in[253]), .input1(253), .input0(input_num[254]), .out(input_num[253]));
...
mux ripple[  0].mux_0(.sel(in[  0]), .input1(  0), .input0(input_num[  1]), .out(input_num[  0]));
```